# How to get params from URI scheme of deep link in React navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, url-scheme

I am using React Navigation 6 to set up URI scheme deep linking, here is how I configured it:

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ["wagal://"],
  config: {
    ResetPassword: {
      path: "reset/password/:token",
      params: {
        token: null,
      },
    },
  },
};

function homeStack() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen component={ResetPassword} name="ResetPassword" />
        //...
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

if I go to `wagal://reset/password?token=123456789` it redirects me to App in reset password screen, but I can't get token parameter from `ResetPassword`:

```
function ResetPassword({ route }) {
  const {token} = route.params;
  // ...
}
```

It is throwing following error:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating route.params.token)`

but if I try to get entire URL in PasswordReset screen using below code, it shows entire URI with token:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
      console.log(`url`, url);
    });
  }, []);
```

Output:

```
wagal://reset/password?token=123456789
```

I can use `slice`, `substring` methods, but there has to be a way to get params with some methods?

Also I tried this `navigation.getParam("token");` but I am getting below error:

`navigation.getParam is not a function`.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm that is strange. Are you following this tutorial https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#passing-params

Comment: I followed this tutorial, still not working

Comment: @MirStephen I am facing the same issue and I had also done the same you did. Did you found any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your config with this one:

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ["wagal://"],
  config: {
    screens:{
      ResetPassword: "reset/password",
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Earlier I made a mistake thinking it is solved, but no. Also I tried above solution and it didn't work either. 

The scheme is `wagal://reset/password?token=eyJhbGc`

Comment: I think it has to be like `ResetPassword: "reset/password:token",` right?

Comment: By the way they have a playground: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#playground

Comment: I can't change deeplink, in deed that is coming from server and I don't have access to source code of that

Comment: Edited my answer again, this will work definitely. Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and I found out this solution to edit in your Navigation stack. I used this tutorial : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/

```
<Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} getId={({ params }) => params.passwordResetId} options={{ headerShown: false, title: "Réinitialiser le mot de passe" }}/>
```

Then I used it in my associated component with this

```
state: {
   id: this.props.match.params.passwordResetId,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue and did the same he did and also got the same results and when I console log the navigation prop and I found that I was not adding that screen, I have the stack screen named as Chats inside it is Bottom tab and first screen name is also Chats and inside it was another stack named as ChatList and this is where I was getting my id but I did not add that screen in my config.

**log of navigation prop**

```
{"key": "ChatList-gtKDVQEF0SlR3o_hInYjm", "name": "ChatList", "params": {"id": undefined}}
```

**after correct config**

```
{"key": "ChatList-gtKDVQEF0SlR3o_hInYjm", "name": "ChatList", "params": {"id": "23"}}
```

**Wrong config**

```
config: {
      screens: {
        Intro:"Intro",
        Chats:{
          screens: {
            Chats: {
              path :'test/:id',
              parse:{
                id: (id) => `${id}`
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    }
```

**Right config**

```
config: {
      screens: {
        Intro:"Intro",
        Chats:{
          screens: {
            Chats: {
              screens: {
                ChatList: {
                  path :'test/:id',
                  parse:{
                    id: (id) => `${id}`
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    }
```

And you can also use [react-native-deep-linking](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-deep-linking) and add some logic and navigate it. This library has some helpful functions.

Comment: bro what is `   path :'test/:id'` from where `test` is coming from?

Comment: test is just a path name, you can use anything, :id is the parameter you had in the link, for example, 
the link of the example I gave must be ending with ...some-link../test/1b2b1k2b1kb2

so by doing the above way you can catch the link id in the screen and you can do anything with that.