# Can't use passed params from deep link with React Navigation V6

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm trying to configure simple linking logic to open app via invitation link
link would be something like this `[scheme]://auth/[invitaion-code]`

So I've configures the following linking object to pass it to the `NavigationContainer`

```
const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
  prefixes: ['my app scheme'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Authorizer: {
        path: "auth/:code",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And defined the following navigation stack:

```
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} linking={linking}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
        initialRouteName={initialRouteName}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Authorizer" component={AuthorizerView} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Now my question is how do I use the `code` param inside of my `AuthorizerView` Component?

I've tried this but it always comes out `undefined`

```
const AuthorizerView: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation }: Props) => {
  const {code} = navigation.params;
```

heres the log of the navigation object:

```
{"addListener": [Function addListener], "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack], "dispatch": [Function dispatch], "getId": [Function getId], "getParent": [Function getParent], "getState": [Function anonymous], "goBack": [Function anonymous], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], "navigate": [Function anonymous], "pop": [Function anonymous], "popToTop": [Function anonymous], "push": [Function anonymous], "removeListener": [Function removeListener], "replace": [Function anonymous], "reset": [Function anonymous], "setOptions": [Function setOptions], "setParams": [Function anonymous]}
```

This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873657/how-to-get-params-from-uri-scheme-of-deep-link-in-react-navigation) question but none of the answers on there worked for me so I'm trying to ask the question again

Comment: The link you have shared has mentioned route.params to get the token but you are doing navigation.params.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a `getInitialURL` and a `subscribe` method to your linking object:

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
import { URLListener } from "expo-linking";

/**
 * Used in `linking` below
 * This is how links are handled by react navigation when the app is opened by the link from quit state.
 * Called on app launch
 */
const getInitialURL = async () => {
  // Get url from deep link
  const initialDeepLinkUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();

  return initialDeepLinkUrl;
};

/**
 * Used in `linking` below.
 * This is how links are handled by react navigation when the app is running.
 */
const subscribe = (listener: (url: string) => void) => {
  // Url listener for adding Linking.addEventListener, calls the listener passed to subscribe
  const onReceiveURL: URLListener = ({ url }) => {
    listener(url);
  };

  // Listen to incoming links from deep linking
  const linkingSubscription = Linking.addEventListener("url", onReceiveURL);

  return () => {
    // Clean up the event listeners
    linkingSubscription.remove();
  };
};
```

Then add these to your linking object :

```
const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
  prefixes: ["my app scheme"],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Authorizer: {
        path: "auth/:code",
      },
    },
  },
  getInitialURL,
  subscribe,
};
```

This worked for me but might seem overkill for your use case. In my case I had a bunch of stuff in these methods for handling opening of notifications.